# Deploying a custom Password Policy file for WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

The documentation on how to create a custom password policy (https://docs.wso2.org/display/IS460/Password+Policies) is lacking details about how to deploy the custom password policy.

Does anyone here have any information about how to deploy the custom code?

Comment: Try to add it in a jar and put it in the directory that contains the main Identity Server jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AdrianMitev mentioned, you have to write java class to enforce new custom Password Policy.

- Create new class as mentioned in the doc.
- Build a jar
- copy it into `<IS_HOME>/repository/components/libs/` folder.
- Then update the configuration file as mentioned in the doc.

HTH,
DarRay